# Camera is centered on character, but doesn't show character in game window

Tags: unity, camera

I'm using Unity 4.6.3. I create an animation from sprite. When I press `Play` button, I see animation plays on scene window, but on Game Window, I don't see anything.

[image]

Here is Inspector for main camera:
[image]

Here is Inspector for Player:
[image]

I have checked that both z = 0 when execute. Please tell me which part I config wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera needs to be in front of the scene (some -Z value) in order to see the scene. The camera can't see things that are at or behind its depth.

Set your camera position to be something like -10 for the Z component of the position. You should notice right away that the camera preview shows your sprite.